# Sprite Sheet Animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I want to create an animated logo for a website, the logo is an atom and the animation is tricky to pull of since its the electrons spinning around in a twisted elliptical path. Now please correct me if I'm wrong but animating this by swapping out a series of images really quickly as is done in 2D games seems the easiest way to go about this.

The reason I ask is I have not found much information on going about this. Is this because it isn't an advisable animation technique for jQuery and javascript or will it load too slowly?

If there is a better way of doing this please tell me, or if it is the best way how do I go about it?

Comment: CSS3 transitions is the way I would go. The only ones who wouldn't see the animations would be the IE8 and under losers. And you can serve them a GIF instead. I wouldn't use javascript as it wouldn't probably hog memory.

Comment: I don't want the animation to play constantly, only when hovered over so IE8 losers would lose out completely, I read transitions weren't available in IE at all

Comment: I have an old website that does something similar to what you want. http://www.deckersdesign.com. the script is called bouncyBoss.js. you will just want the basic parts that change the image. it is fully cross browser compatible last time i checked. and it doesn't take up too much memory for just animating one image.

Comment: You could be right, I thought IE9 had some support, but I might be wrong about that. I usually don't care much for IE users. As long as the webpage is presentable and works I'm good. So they lose out on some fluff animations, so what. It's not worth the extra page weight to always make sure they get stuff that in the end isn't crucial to a page's functionality.

Comment: I would still look into CSS3. No matter what, javascript animations and stuff on mobile seems to always lag or have unintended consequences. CSS3 transitions and animations almost always look good on mobile devices.

Comment: Well I cant argue with that. but check out my jsfiddle anyway! :) http://jsfiddle.net/wh1t3w0lf21/u5Y6H/1/